# Reinstall Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I am facing a problem with my project.

> The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

[image]

This has happened before and I solved it by reinstalling the Nuget Package Manager using a command. Unfortunately, I am not finding that command again. I tried to find the solution online but everything I am getting is installing/reinstalling NuGet packages and not package manager.

Found this article: https://forums.asp.net/t/1776324.aspx?How+to+install+upgrade+VS+NuGet+Package+Manager+ but It's not applicable here.

NuGet Package Manager is preinstalled in VS2019 and no separate package to download and install. Also, there's not Extension Manage in VS2019 like older versions.

Please Let me know the command to reinstall NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: close solution, delete obj folder and open solution again.

Comment: Did that. Not working

Comment: Can you not download nuget command line from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) or [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/search?q=nuget) or brew?

Comment: @Prateek : Did you get the question? I want actual command, not command line tool. Besides, NuGet is preinstalled in VS2019, no external tool available.

Comment: also try to delete the **.vs** folder where vs stores user data. I doubt that reinstalling nuget fixes the issue.

Comment: @magicandre1981 : I faced this problem earlier and was solved by reinstalling nuget. Still, will try your solution but let me know about reinstalling nuget

Comment: @magicandre1981 :  Thanks man. It did the trick. Deleting the .vs folder solved the issue. Unfortunately I don't know the facepalm emoji. :D

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer, so that you can [accept the reply as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) to "close" the question.

Comment: @Mahadev command to install will just do the same thing as installation.like choco install nuget-command-line. your question was unclear. good that its solved

Comment: @Morse This question is so clear and I need to know how could reinstall Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Such nuget restore issues can normally fix by deleting the obj folder where the nuget files like `project.assets.json`, `projectname.csproj.nuget.g.targets`, `projectname.csproj.nuget.g.props`, `projectname.csproj.nuget.dgspec.json` and `projectnamecsproj.nuget.cache` are stored.

If this still doesn't fix it, delete the [hidden `.vs` folder](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Aug/07/Fixing-Visual-Studio-Intellisense-Errors) inside the solution, where Visual Studio stores the user settings for the project.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer here. However, in this case, deleting the `obj` folder didn't work but deleting `.vs` folder did the trick. :)

Comment: @Mahadev I just wanted to add it as reference for others where the first step my help.

Comment: deleting the .vs folder did the trick. It proposed to upgrade the project to the new standard.