# The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-standard-2.0

I've created a .NET standard library (2.0) which is calling a web service (written in .NET framework). When I call a method of web service, I get below error.

```
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
error CS0012: The type 'System.Enum' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
```

I'm using VS 2019 Enterprise (Version 16.4.0).

Comment: Calling it via http-request or method call?

Comment: yes, calling it like below.

var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(endpointAddress);

Comment: Please put the relevant code in thr question and also try to create an [MRE]

Comment: Actually my web service is running on secure network so wont be accessible on public network.

Comment: This looks like a nuget package issue as diffrent versions of System.Runtime are installed in both projects. Did you manually install System.Runtime through nuget in your project?

Comment: which windows version and .net version do you use?

Comment: @DKar No. I've not added System.Runtime manually. Not sure how .NET standard uses System.Runtime

Comment: @magicandre1981 Windows 10, .NET framework 4.7.2, .NET standard 2.0

Comment: ok, .net 4.7.2 is .net standard 2.0 compatible, so try to [delete obj/bin and if this doesn't help the .vs folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306579/1466046). This "helps" to fix some strange errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over netstandard project - make it multitargeting to resolve the issue

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net471</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have mix of .Net 4.7.1 and netstandard 2.0 projects - and serialization of mixed classes from both fails with the mentioned error.
After long investigations and unlucky workarounds I've found the thread disclosing root-causes. Microsoft closed it as "won't fix, use multitargeting"
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/21373