# System.TypeLoadException: 'VTable setup of type Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices failed'

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I am new to Xamarin and currently I have to make some change to one of the existing application .
But When i try to load the projects , initially there were lots of error related to version code.I somehow managed to overcome those error  but i got struck to this error .

System.TypeLoadException: 'VTable setup of type Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices failed'[image]

Firstly I believed this error might be related to Xamarin Form version no .But I have tried that one too but no luck.In Error log I can see

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU5048  The 'PackageIconUrl'/'iconUrl' element is deprecated. Consider using the 'PackageIcon'/'icon' element instead. Learn more at https://aka.ms/deprecateIconUrl    IniFileParser   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.300\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets  198

Any help will be appreciated .

Comment: Do you use the FFImageLoading when you get the issue? Have you test a new project? Does it throw the same error?

Comment: I haven't checked for FFImageLoading . I will check this out .

Comment: Any update for this problem?

Comment: I run into [the issues, too](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11157). When I use packages.config, the app starts fine.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT  No , I am not  using FFImageloading.

Comment: @MiniChip Have you check with the new project? Does it throw the same error? If no, check the code. If it ispossible, could you provide the code which cause the error？

Comment: for me the issue was gone today. try [delete bin/obj/.vs folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306579/1466046) or clone a new working copy

Answer (score 4):

When I get the following type of error:

```
VTable setup of Type ??? failed.
```

I've found that the cause is multiple versions of the same dlls, such that version compiled against is different to the version deployed.

If you look at VSs (Debug) Output window, you will likely see errors like (When running with Debugging):

```
"Could not resolve type with token 0100015a from typeref"
```

This can be caused by upgrading one of your projects to depend on a newer version of a library and neglecting to do that for all you projects.

To fix, Find the type mentioned next to `Could not resolve type with token 0100015a from typeref` message, and ensure all references to it's containing dll are of the same version.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by the following:

1. Go to: Help > Check for Updates
2. Installed the latest update
3. Went to: Build > Rebuild Solution

After that I was able to run the debugger on the Android emulator and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` and `Xamarin.AndroidX.AppCompat packagaes` to the latest version. It helped me.