# System.TypeLoadException Message=VTable setup of type Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices failed

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2022

I got an error when trying to run my old project. See the error log below

```
System.TypeLoadException
  Message=VTable setup of type Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices failed 


    0x6 in Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init C#
    0x71 in ....Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate C#
    0x11 in Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/monoandroid10/android-29/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:2726,4  C#
    0x9 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:121,5    C#


Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
07-05 17:47:59.823  pixel_5_-_api_28    Error   11237   AndroidRuntime  android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.TypeLoadException: VTable setup of type Xamarin.Forms.Forms+AndroidPlatformServices failed
  at Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (Android.Content.Context activity, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00006] in <3a92ee483a4c4993b499f9c6bb09c7b9>:0 
  at ....Droid.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x0006f] in <b05d01ba205c485a9295cb6be11f71ec>:0 
  at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) [0x0000f] in <13edebda722843189e7f18d03349106f>:0 
  at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V (_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr klazz, System.IntPtr p0) [0x00005] in <13edebda722843189e7f18d03349106f>:0 
    at crc649c631d1a2337722a.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method)
    at crc649c631d1a2337722a.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I have followed the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62447717/system-typeloadexception-vtable-setup-of-type-xamarin-forms-formsandroidplatf) and tried to update the VS2022 to the latest update 17.6.4 but still no luck.

In some GitHub Issue [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11157) someone mentioned upgrading the latest XF. Mine is version 5.0.0.2578

Here is the package reference:

```
<Reference Include="ExifLib, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\ExifLib.PCL.1.0.1\lib\portable-net45+sl50+win+WindowsPhoneApp81+wp80+Xamarin.iOS10+MonoAndroid10+MonoTouch10\ExifLib.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="FormsViewGroup, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.3.0.967583\lib\MonoAndroid10\FormsViewGroup.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="GCM.Client">
      <HintPath>..\Components\GCMClient-1.0\lib\android\GCM.Client.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Java.Interop" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.0.3\lib\monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.3.0.3\lib\monoandroid\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Ext.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
    <Reference Include="Mono.Android.Export" />
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.12.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="OxyPlot, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=638079a8f0bd61e9, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\OxyPlot.Core.1.0.0\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1+Xamarin.iOS10\OxyPlot.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android.1.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid10\OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PCLCrypto, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d4421c8a4786956c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\PCLCrypto.2.0.147\lib\MonoAndroid23\PCLCrypto.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PInvoke.BCrypt, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e300f9f87f04a7a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\PInvoke.BCrypt.0.3.152\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10\PInvoke.BCrypt.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PInvoke.Kernel32, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e300f9f87f04a7a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\PInvoke.Kernel32.0.3.152\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10\PInvoke.Kernel32.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PInvoke.NCrypt, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e300f9f87f04a7a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\PInvoke.NCrypt.0.3.152\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10\PInvoke.NCrypt.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="PInvoke.Windows.Core, Version=0.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9e300f9f87f04a7a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\PInvoke.Windows.Core.0.3.152\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10\PInvoke.Windows.Core.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Connectivity, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.3.2.0\lib\MonoAndroid10\Plugin.Connectivity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Connectivity.3.2.0\lib\MonoAndroid10\Plugin.Connectivity.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.CurrentActivity, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Plugin.CurrentActivity.2.1.0.2\lib\monoandroid44\Plugin.CurrentActivity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Media, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xam.Plugin.Media.4.0.1.5\lib\monoandroid71\Plugin.Media.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Plugin.Permissions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Plugin.Permissions.3.0.0.12\lib\monoandroid71\Plugin.Permissions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SignaturePad, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.3.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid\SignaturePad.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="SignaturePad.Forms, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms.3.0.0\lib\MonoAndroid\SignaturePad.Forms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\monoandroid\System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Primitives, Version=4.2.29.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.2.2.29\lib\monoandroid\System.Net.Http.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="Validation, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2fc06f0d701809a7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Validation.2.3.7\lib\dotnet\Validation.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Core.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.LiveData.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel.1.1.1.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Arch.Lifecycle.ViewModel.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.AsyncLayoutInflater.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Collections.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.CoordinaterLayout.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.CursorAdapter.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomView.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.DocumentFile.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.DrawerLayout.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Interpolator.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Loader.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.LocalBroadcastManager.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Print, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Print.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Print.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.SlidingPaneLayout.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.SwipeRefreshLayout.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.VersionedParcelable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager.28.0.0.1\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Android.Support.ViewPager.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Essentials.1.1.0\lib\monoandroid90\Xamarin.Essentials.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578\lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578\lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.3.3.0.967583\lib\MonoAndroid10\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Xamarin.Forms.Xaml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Xamarin.Forms.5.0.0.2578\lib\netstandard2.0\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Any idea? I have tried to update all references to the latest version but it more causing more errors. I hope someone could help me here. Thanks in advance.