# Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified HRESULT: 0x80131045

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webserver

I've searched but I can't find a solution
I ha a Xamarin Forms App in visual studio so I have 5 project in my solution:

```
MagCoils
MagCoils.Android
MagCoils.iOS
MagCoils.UWP
MagCoils.WebService
```

I work only with MagCoils, MagCoils.Android and MagCoils.WebService... never tested iOS and UWP.
After switch form Visual Studio 2017 community to Visual Studio 2019 Community and upgrading some packages....  when I set MagCoils.WebService as StartUp project and Debug it with Chrome I run in this page error that Could not load file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS' or one of its dependencies.

I don't know how to proceed to resolve this error, I'm new with all this things, Xamarin, C# and WebSerivice but this project/solution always work well before this upgrade but I don't know which upgrade couse me the problem.

**Trace of assembly loading**

```
Assembly manager loaded from: C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ clr.dll
Running with the executable C: \ Program Files (x86) \ IIS Express \ iisexpress.exe
Detailed error log follows.

Information about the pre-association status
REG: DisplayName = Xamarin.iOS
 (Partial)
AVV: Partial binding information specified for an assembly:
AVV: assembly name: Xamarin.iOS | Domain ID: 3
AVV: Partial association occurs when only part of the assembly display name is specified.
AVV: This could cause the binder to load an incorrect assembly.
AVV: It is advisable to specify a full text identity for the assembly,
AVV - Consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
AVV: For more information and common solutions to this issue, see the white paper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270.
REG: Appbase = file: /// F: / C Programs / MagCoils / MagCoils / MagCoils.WebService /
REG: Initial PrivatePath = F: \ Program Files C \ MagCoils \ MagCoils \ MagCoils.WebService \ bin
Calling assembly: (Unknown).

REG: The association originates in the default load context.
REG: using the application configuration file: F: \ Program Files C \ MagCoils \ MagCoils \ MagCoils.WebService \ web.config
REG: using host configuration file: C: \ Users \ arglu \ Documents \ IISExpress \ config \ aspnet.config
REG: Using the computer configuration file from C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ config \ machine.config.
LOG: Policies are not currently applied to the reference (private, custom, partial, or path-based assembly binding).
REG: Attempt to download new URL file: /// C: / Users / arglu / AppData / Local / Temp / Temporary ASP.NET Files / vs / 859f2ce6 / 8d561023 / Xamarin.iOS.DLL.
REG: Attempt to download new URL file: /// C: / Users / arglu / AppData / Local / Temp / Temporary ASP.NET Files / vs / 859f2ce6 / 8d561023 / Xamarin.iOS / Xamarin.iOS.DLL.
REG: Attempt to download new URL file: /// F: / C Programs / MagCoils / MagCoils / MagCoils.WebService / bin / Xamarin.iOS.DLL.
REG: using the application configuration file: F: \ Program Files C \ MagCoils \ MagCoils \ MagCoils.WebService \ web.config
REG: using host configuration file: C: \ Users \ arglu \ Documents \ IISExpress \ config \ aspnet.config
REG: Using the computer configuration file from C: \ Windows \ Microsoft.NET \ Framework \ v4.0.30319 \ config \ machine.config.
REG: post-criteria reference: Xamarin.iOS, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 84e04ff9cfb79065
ERR: The assembly installation could not be completed (hr = 0x80131045). The survey has been completed.
```

**Stack trace:**

```
[FileLoadException: The file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. Verification of strong name signature failed. The assembly may have been tampered with or has delayed signature, but is only partially signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)]

[FileLoadException: The file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. Verification of strong name signature failed. The assembly may have been tampered with or has delayed signature, but is only partially signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad (AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, BooleanSecurity + suppress0)
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad (AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean + suppressSecurity)
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName (AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection9, suppressecurity9)
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad (String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +80
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad (String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark & ​​stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +22
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load (String assemblyString) +29
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper (String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: The file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. Verification of strong name signature failed. The assembly may have been tampered with or has delayed signature, but is only partially signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper (String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +726
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory () +196
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly (AssemblyInfo ai) +45
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies (CompilationSection compConfig) +172
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies () +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods (String preStartInitListPath, Boolean & isRefAssemblyLoaded) +111
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart () +156
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize (ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +695

[HttpException (0x80004005): The file or assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version = 0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 84e04ff9cfb79065' or one of its dependencies could not be loaded. Verification of strong name signature failed. The assembly may have been tampered with or has delayed signature, but is only partially signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit (HttpContext context) +660
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit (HttpContext context) +89
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate (IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +188
```

Comment: [clear obj/bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306579/1466046) and rebuild apps

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot !!!

Comment: you will do this deleting very often, it will "fix" a lot of errors you'll get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reinstall Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286839/reinstall-nuget-package-manager-in-visual-studio-2019)