# .NET Core solution build gives a GenerateDepsFile error

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, msbuild, nuget

**Environment**

- Visual Studio 2019 (latest SP upto Dec 2020)
- .NET Core 3.1 with latest SP up to Dec 2020
- WebAPI project with lots of child DLLs being loaded at runtime

**Problem Context**

When the solution is build, a "**`GenerateDepsFile:`**" error is given by MS Build for a particular project in the solution. It tries to add an item to a dictionary when it already exists, but not which dictionary it is trying or what duplicate key is being attempted.

**Exploration Performed**

- There are no compilation errors (apart from Deps file)
- All referenced projects are building fine with no errors in themselves
- All NuGet references are available with no errors
- Clean and Rebuild all solutions involved
- Manually delete the `obj`and `bin` folders across codebase

Comment: generating the .deps.json fails. try [clean obj/bin/.vs folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306579/1466046)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I have tried to delete whole bin and obj folders already, apart from VS own Clean operation (if that's the reason for the downvote)

Comment: I haven't down voted. change logging to verbose/diagnostic to see more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of exploration, it looked like a multi version NuGet package scenario (cleaned the NuGet cache already)

Finally I went to all child projects and validated if the same version of all NuGet package is being used across. It turned out that the version of some assemblies ( esp Microsoft.Data.SqlClient) were different in child projects and the calling project.
Since the projects themselves were building all fine, this was not reported on project level, but when those DLLs were getting consumed in parent one, it start giving the error.

It turned out the child projects were built a while back with the latest version available at that time. The parent project was just referencing the DLLs from the output folder and was not aware of previous version and got its own version updated..

So, do ensure that when a particular version of NuGet is approved at one place, that gets updated across the whole eco-system!

However MS should update the error to at least point what dictionary is failing with what specific key in the main message as its very hard to debug with the verbose log.

Answer (score 2):

`The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly` is too large and you should check its detailed build log to judge what is the real problem.

Under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Projects and Solutions**-->**Build and Run**--> set **MSBuild project build output verbosity** to `Detailed` and then build again to get its detailed log.

**Also**, you can share the detailed error build log here with us.

**Maybe** you could check these suggestions:

**1)** [clean nuget caches](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all cache file under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`.

**2)** do not forget to delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin`, `obj` folder of the project, and then use `dotnet restore` command or `msbuild -t:restore` command to restore these files.

**3)** update VS2019 to the latest `16.8.4` and your Net Core 3.1 Sdk to [the latest 3.1.11](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1).

Comment: Thanks @perry. I finally got it working by going deep the project references. However, the message should include which key is getting violated when adding to the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

> The "GenerateDepsFile" task failed unexpectedly.

I believe You just need to **delete the bin and obj folder and then Clean and Rebuild solution.**

this should work, It work for me after going through many approaches.

**Edit:**

This worked for me as well where as a Clean Solution didn't. Please take a backup of your bin & obj folders before you delete them as there are rare scenario's where this could back fire on you and cost you a lot of work.