# Suddenly unable to use Microsoft.UI.Xaml on UWP app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I'm new to uwp development and I've been messing around for the last couple days. I've been using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` just fine until a few minutes ago after I tried cleaning the project. Since then the package no longer works and these errors keep popping.

[[image: errors]


<sup>click to enlarge</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3jUZ.png)

I tried rebuilding the project and even creating a new one but even then, I couldn't get the package to work again.
Any idea if I can fix this or should I reinstall VS2019, SDK etc..

EDIT:
As per Nico's comment below, deleting the package folder from the nuget folder and downloading it again will fix the issue. You'll have to build again before the errors disappear.

Comment: Without the Code of your MainPage its hard to tell what the problem is

Comment: problem is there isn't anything custom to post here. For instance just adding the XamlControlsResources tag to Application.Resources per the Getting started guide throws the first error in the image

Comment: [delete obj/bin folder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306579/1466046) or the hidden **.vs** folder

Comment: I'm afraid you need clean Visual Studio nuget cache folder manually, please go to`C:\Users\useraccount\.nuget\packages` folder and find `Microsoft.UI.Xaml` folder and delete it, and reinstall this nuget for your  project

Comment: Worked like a charm! cleaning the nuget cash, re-installing the package and building fixed the issue. Thanks chief!