# Not able to compile my Xamarin.Android application after upgrading to Xamarin.forms version 5.0.0.2012

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Error APT2259: 'textEnd' is incompatible with attribute iconGravity (attr) flags [start=1, textStart=2] [weak]. (APT2259)
Error APT2061: failed linking file resources. (APT2061)

Comment: make sure you have aapt2 enabled in properties of your android app

Comment: Yes.. it's Enabled

Comment: [clean obj/bin folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61306579/1466046) and try again.

Comment: Yes.. I will clean obj and bin files in my project and build the android project, but it will show same errors

Comment: migrate [Android support libs to AndroidX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx#migration-tooling)

Comment: Yes.. I will migrate to AndroidX

Comment: Even I migrate, same issue will rise in android project

Comment: have you cleaned obj/bin again after migration?

Comment: Yes after migration, I clean the obj and bin files, but it show same error

Comment: in the styles.xml files in android project, replace android with androidx names. Also add type="id" for item entries. here is already an issue about it: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13303 check what helps

Comment: as per your comment I will replace the androidx and also add type="id" for all items.

Comment: Error APT2260: style attribute 'androidx:attr/background' not found. (APT2260) 
Error APT2260: style attribute 'androidx:attr/buttonStyle' not found. (APT2260) 
Error APT2260: style attribute 'androidx:attr/datePickerDialogTheme' not found. 
Error APT2260: style attribute 'androidx:attr/dropDownHorizontalOffset' not found. (APT2260) 
Error APT2260: style attribute 'androidx:attr/dropDownVerticalOffset' not found. (APT2260) 
Error APT2260: style attribute 'androidx:attr/popupMenuStyle' not found. (APT2260)

Comment: raise an issue on github and post your old styles.xml, so maybe the XF team has an idea how to fix it.

Comment: Ok.. I will rise in GitHub

Comment: This is link, I will rise issue https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14368

Comment: GitHub guys are not responding the bug, is it any other way to resolve this issue

Comment: the team also works on new lib MAUI, so repsonse time is slow. if former version workd, ditch your changes and use last XF versions

Comment: ok.. I will look into this again, MAUI lib is available, please let me know

Comment: MAUI will be released with [.NET6 in November 2021](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/FAQs#when-will-net-maui-be-available)

Comment: Yes.. it will come from November.. mean while, if you now more information, please give a comment

Answer (score 0):

The solution, at least for me, was to migrate using the [AndroidX migration tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/androidx#migration-tooling) mentioned in the comment.

###### You need to enable it first if you haven't already done so:

Enable the AndroidX Migrator via Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > "Enable AndroidX Migrator"

[image]

###### Then use the tool to migrate the project:

Right-click your project and Migrate to AndroidX

[image]

Hope that helped.

(Screenshot have been taken from the doc itself)